# What is the term for being able to understand only the auditory form of a language?

Tags: terminology

What is the term for the condition of not being able to read, write, or even speak a particular language, but only being able to understand the auditory form of a language. For example, a boy could only understand Chinese in auditory form, but he replies to his parents in English.

Comment: If the boy can understand Chinese in auditory form, he will be able to speak Chinese at some level too, even though he prefers speaking English because he's better at that. The better he is at hearing/understanding, the better he will be able to speak.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a single most used term for this specific level of proficiency, but I think it classifies as elementary proficiency (IRL scale level 1). There are numerous proficiency scales though.

Comment: Auditorily proficient?

Comment: @Robbert Understanding a language and speaking it are two quite distinct mental processes, and they each require training. If someone has listened to a language non-natively for most of his life, but has never been encouraged to speak it and never tried, he might well be almost entirely unable to put together a sentence in that language, despite understanding nearly everything said to him. This is also a common stage in language learners; for example, when I moved to China, I had heard enough Mandarin to understand it fairly well, but I could barely stutter out even basic sentences myself.

Comment: Illiterate mute

Comment: How old is the boy? If he is only three or four, he will eventually speak in Chinese if both his parents continue talking to him in their mother tongue. It's not atypical with children growing up in families where two or more languages are heard and spoken. E.g the mother speaks one language, the father another and the country of residence has a different language altogether.

Comment: Good command of spoken Chinese, though no written competence.

Comment: I would say he has a passive understanding of spoken Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

If a person can understand verbal communication in a language but can neither read nor write, he would be considered *illiterate* in that language.

Many people who begin to study a language find understanding verbal communication easier than speaking it. At first, speaking requires retrieving words from memory.

Comment: _Illiterate_ would be when you can’t read or write a language. It has nothing to do with your ability to _speak_ the language.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But the term *illiterate* has far too much of a pejorative sense to be used in an instance such as this. I would not dream of saying, for example 'Professor Jacquet (who happens to speak and write 23 languages) is illiterate in the language of the north-west Amazonian Indians.

Comment: @WS2 That is true as well. (And I’d love to meet this Professor Jacquet—I didn’t know I had such prodigious namesakes!)

Comment: Gary's Student is making the distinction between comprehension of spoken language, and being able to expressively speak.  That is a normal stage of child development.  Comprehension is usually ahead of expression....There are societies where most adults are illiterate, so the context may explain if that use is pejorative.